# Cupy array construction from existing GPU pointer

Tags: python, gpu, pycuda, cupy

I would like to construct a Cupy GPU array view of the array that already exists on the GPU and I'm handed the following:

1. Pointer to the array.
2. I know the data type and the size of the data.
3. I'm also given a pitch.

How one would construct an array view (avoiding copies preferably)? I tried the following:

```py
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np 

shape = (w, h, c, b) # example
s = np.product(shape)*4 # this is 1D 

mem = cp.cuda.UnownedMemory(ptr=image_batch_ptr,
                            owner=None,
                            size=s)
memptr = cp.cuda.MemoryPointer(mem, 0)
d = cp.ndarray(shape=shape,
               dtype=np.float32,
               memptr=memptr)
```

But this does not seem to produce the correct alignment. Specifically, I'm having trouble with integrating pitch into the picture -- is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve it. This is indeed possible with `cupy` but requires first moving (on device) 2D allocation to 1D allocation with [`copy.cuda.runtime.memcpy2D`](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.cuda.runtime.memcpy2D.html)

1. We initialise an empty `cp.empty`
2. We copy the data from 2D allocation to that array using `cupy.cuda.runtime.memcpy2D`, there we can set the pitch and width. We use `MemoryKind kind = 3` which is the device to device copy.

This seems to be the optimal way to create a proper `cp.ndarray` without moving to host.